# need help to optimize php iteration

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts

In order for me to get the data I need to iterate though different tables to get the data I need.

I have my quires that are giving me arrays and I have to iterate through them and calculate and so an so forth

below is a sample code:

```
$CompanyDepartmentandUserWiseDataString = array();

            foreach($Arrays1 as $Array1)
            {
                foreach($Arrays2 as $Array2)
                {
                    if($Array2->id == $Array1->id)
                    {
                        $SelectedCompanyDepartmentPercentage = calculate y;                        

                            foreach($Arrays3 as $Array3)
                            {
                                if($Array3->id == $Array1->id)
                                {
                                  $CompanyDepartmentandUserWiseDataString[] = list the catagories;  
                                }
                            }                 

                            foreach($Arrays3 as $Array3)
                            {                            
                                if($Array3->id == $Array1->id)
                                {
                                    foreach($Arrays4 as $Array4)
                                    {                                        
                                        if($Array4->id == $Array3->id)
                                        {
                                            $SelectedCompanyDepartmentUserPercentage = calculate data;

                                            foreach($Arrays5 as $Array5)
                                            {
                                                if($Array5->id == $Array4->id)
                                                    $CompanyDepartmentandUserWiseDataString[] = print;
                                                }

                                            }

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                    }
                }               

            }

            return $CompanyDepartmentandUserWiseDataString;
```

the above code is generating the following:

```
data = [{ y: 55.11, color: colors[0]

         }, {
             y: 21.63, color: colors[1], drilldown: {
               name: 'Firefox versions', categories: ['Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 2.0'], level: 1,
                                         data: [13.52, 5.43, 1.58, 0.83, 0.20], 
                      color: colors[1]
            }
         }, {
            y: 11.94, color: colors[2], drilldown: {
               name: 'Chrome versions', categories: ['Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0', 'Chrome 12.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 7.0'], 
                                        data: [9.91, 0.50, 0.36, 0.32, 0.22, 0.19, 0.12, 0.12], 
                      color: colors[2]
            }
         }, {
            y: 7.15, color: colors[3], drilldown: {
               name: 'Safari versions', categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon', 'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 41'], 
                                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14], 
                      color: colors[3]
            }
         }, {
            y: 2.14, color: colors[4], drilldown: {
               name: 'Opera versions', categories: ['Opera 11.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 9.x'], 
                                       data: [1.65, 0.37, 0.12], 
               color: colors[4]
            }
         }];
```

How can I optimize this to speed up performance. the system is very slow

please help

Comment: if id is uniq you should add a `break` at the end of the if. And you have a duplicate loop for Array3

Comment: yes, one  array3 is generating string array and another is generating int

Comment: Why are you using two loops instead of one for array3? You could use one, that's sufficient.

Comment: Also, can you tell us what you want to do with this code? It'd be also nice to provide a sample. For me it just looks like a big mess. The other question is, how do you get the data? From a mysql database?

Comment: true! can have one loop for array3, but still we have others

Comment: I get from MySQL queries, that are joining

Comment: just added what the loop is generating

Comment: I think have `id` as the `key` of your array will simplify the code and increase the speed

Comment: @Ôrel you are saying: foreach(Arrays1 as $key=>$val ) {} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first do some preprocessing to turn your arrays to associative arrays, where every entry is keyed by its id:

```
function keyArray($arr) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($arr as $element) {
        $result[$element->id] = $element;
    }
    return $result;
}

$keyedArrays2 = keyArray($Arrays2);
$keyedArrays3 = keyArray($Arrays3);
$keyedArrays4 = keyArray($Arrays4);
$keyedArrays5 = keyArray($Arrays5);
```

Then the job becomes a lot easier, as you will only have one loop over the first array, and will be able to find the matching elements in the other arrays without any further looping:

```
foreach($Arrays1 as $Array1)
{
    if (isset($keyedArrays2[$Array1->id])) {
        $Array2 = $keyedArrays2[$Array1->id];
        // make calculations that depend on $Array2
    }
    if (isset($keyedArrays3[$Array1->id])) {
        $Array3 = $keyedArrays3[$Array1->id];
        // make calculations that depend on $Array3
    }
    if (isset($keyedArrays4[$Array1->id])) {
        $Array4 = $keyedArrays4[$Array1->id];
        // make calculations that depend on $Array4
    }
    if (isset($keyedArrays5[$Array1->id])) {
        $Array5 = $keyedArrays5[$Array1->id];
        // make calculations that depend on $Array5
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an update to deal with cases where the ID does not exist in any of the arrays.

Comment: I get Undefined offset: 54! any reason